# How to recover entire backup file to MySql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, backup, mysql-error-1046, mysql-error-1049

I have a backup mySQL database file which contains a few table structures and a few default records. But when I try to recover to the new database and new system that I just installed, it fails.

How can I recover the file 'db' to mysql?

```
$ mysql --user=root < /media/Iomega_HDD/20110416/db
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected
$ mysql --user=root localhost < /media/Iomega_HDD/20110416/db
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`mysql -u root -p DATABASE_NAME_GOES_HERE < input.sql`

The -p switch tells it you're going to type in a password. Because you HAVE set a password on your MySQL root account, right?  Right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
mysql> create database DatabaseName;
mysql> use DatabaseName;
mysql> source /media/Iomega_HDD/20110416/db
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -u root -p`

then run the backup script `source yourscript.backup`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all through the command line.

`$ mysql --user=root databasename < /media/Iomega_HDD/20110416/db`